# AddThis toolbox multiple items

Tags: javascript, php, addthis

I am trying to use the addThis toolbox for multiple items on a page. I have been reading that I need to use the addthis:url property to generate the correct URL for the individual items.

What I have is the following:

```
    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-535e7a2916e104ff" async="async"></script>

    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
    <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" style="margin-bottom:20px;" addthis:title="THE TITLE" addthis:description="THE DESCRIPTION" addthis:url="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>"></div>
```

This doesn't seem to do anything? It only echos out in the div but doesn't actually change the share so that it is specific to the item.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I feel you are missing in src of javascript code, Path looks like breaked

Comment: No, the path is correct. That is the code addThis generates when you create on their site. It works for individual pages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addthis:title, addthis:description, and addthis:url parameters are for use with our older advanced configuration tools - the ones with the button code inside.

For this to work with the addthis_sharing_toolbox you'll need to use this code:

```
 <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-535e7a2916e104ff" async="async"></script>

<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" style="margin-bottom:20px;" data-title="THE TITLE" data-url="<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>"></div>
```

Also, you only need to have the addthis_widget.js once on every page. The position usually doesn't matter (unless there's some kind of race condition with other JavaScript on the page), but you shouldn't have it more than once since it will slow down page loading.

Comment: Thank you Paul.

How would you include a description?

Comment: Almost none of the services we support adding a description. Is there a specific service you're sharing to that you want to include a description for?

Comment: No forget that. I just thought it was an important parameter to pass also. No worries ;-)